# Is there a way to see commits before a specific commit on Github website?

Tags: github

On stash we can do commits?until=commithash to show all commits before a specific commit, but is there a way we do the same on Github website?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can view **commits until a specified commit** on GitHub by using the below url

```
https://github.com/{user}/{repo}/commits/{commitHash}
```

For example, to view the commits until a specified commit hash for the `spring-projects/spring-authorization-server` repo, you would have to visit

```
https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-authorization-server/commits/28ac43bd503db92a13ec91698120e14af2ecc10d
```

Comment: that works, thanks a lot!